# How is java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentLinkedQueue#head updated after initialisation?

Tags: java

Environment:
java :`java version "1.8.0_201"`
os:`Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS Linux version 4.15.0-91-generic`

Recently I read the source code of `java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentLinkedQueue#offer`, and I am confused with the code below.

```
public boolean offer(E e){
        checkNotNull(e);
        final Node<E> newNode = new Node<E>(e);

        for (Node<E> t = tail, p = t; ; ) {
          Node<E> q = p.next;
          if (q == null) {
            // p is last node
            if (p.casNext(null, newNode)) {
            ......
```

when `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` is initialized, the `item` of `head` and `tail` is null.

```
 public ConcurrentLinkedQueue() {
        head = tail = new Node<E>(null);
    }
```

but after I first invoke  `ConcurrentLinkedQueue#offer`(with `queue.offer(1)`) and the code executed the line
`p.casNext(null, newNode)`(here `p` and `head` are the same reference), the reference of `head` was changed to `newNode`,and 'item' value of head was change to `1`.
Detail of `p.casNext` is like this

```
        boolean casNext(Node<E> cmp, Node<E> val) {
            return UNSAFE.compareAndSwapObject(this, nextOffset, cmp, val);
        }
```

It seems only next filed of head was modified in the cas method, but why was the reference of head changed?
Can you give me some explation? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is your problem solved? I also encountered the same problem.

Comment: Yes, the  problem is solved, you can read the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

> It seems only next field of head was modified, how is the reference of head changed?

Correct, `head.next` was changed.

The `head` field of the queue is intentionally not modified by the `offer(e)` method.

The `head` and `tail` fields of the queue are never `null`, so when the queue is empty, they both refer to the same node, and that node has `item = null`. It is always valid for one or more nodes to have `item = null`. Those nodes will be skipped when querying or polling the queue.

It's all done that way to make the code thread-safe without the use of locking.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I'm sorry for having not describing                                                                                            the question clearly. After I invoke  `queue.offer(1)`, the reference of head was changed to the `newNode` and the `item` of `head` was `1`, not  `null` any more. I don't know why the reference of `head` was changed after invoking p.casNext. I've modified the question a little.

Comment: In Java 8, the call to `offer()` does *not* update `head`. You say it did, but how do you know? Did you use a debugger? Using a **debugger** would show you the content, which means it **calls `toString()`**, which calls `iterator()`, which calls `new Itr()`, which calls `advance()`, which calls `first()`, which calls `updateHead(h, p)`, which calls `casHead(h, p)`, **which updates the `head` field**. --- The cleanup of dummy nodes (nodes with `item = null`) is deferred, meaning that pure accessor methods may actually update the internal state, but that ok, since it has no external effect.

Comment: Yes, I used a debugger. And I viewed the code again,  it's actually effected by `toString`. Thanks for your reply, it helps me a lot.